# How to move green character for use onkey in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to move this Green character for use keyboard left&right.

However, the code below shows that the picture is still and moves separately. Here is my code:

```
import turtle

A = turtle.Turtle()
A.speed(0)
A.hideturtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

def MyGoto(A,x_xx,x_yy):
 A.penup()
 A.goto(x_xx,x_yy)
 A.pendown()

def DrawCircle(A,x_xx, x_yy, x_radius, x_color):
 MyGoto(A,x_xx,x_yy)
 A.color(x_color)
 A.fillcolor(x_color)
 A.begin_fill()
 A.circle(x_radius)
 A.end_fill()

global_xx = 10
def left():
 global global_xx
 turtle.backward(global_xx)

def right():
 global global_xx
 turtle.forward(global_xx)

def MySmile(A,global_xx,yy,wr):
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy-100*wr,150*wr,'green')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx-40*wr,yy+60*wr,30*wr,'white')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx-40*wr,yy+60*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+50*wr,yy+60*wr,40*wr,'white')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+50*wr,yy+60*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy+20*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy-80*wr,40*wr,'brown')

MySmile(A,0,0,0.3)

screen.onkey(left, "Left") #this is keyboard code
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.listen()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this but I think the most satisfactory will be to define a custom turtle cursor using a compound shape.  Then we change the shape of the turtle to that custom shape (tilt it) and move it about the screen like any other turtle cursor.

> This is not working in trinket.io website TypeError : TypeError:
>   () got an unexpected keyword argument 'visible' on line 39
>   in main.py – 박준영

This won't *ever* run on ***trinket.io*** as it's missing the `Shape` class and the ability to create custom turtle cursors. You need to edit your question to explicitly mention this constraint.

Let's go about this another way, similar to @tomasantunes but we'll make the redraws instantaneous through judicious use of the `tracer()` method which trinket.io does support:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

global_xx = 0

def drawCircle(turtle, x, y, radius, color):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(radius)
    turtle.end_fill()

def mySmile(turtle, x, y, wr):

    turtle.clear()

    drawCircle(turtle, x + 0 * wr, y - 100 * wr, 150 * wr, 'green')
    drawCircle(turtle, x - 40 * wr, y + 60 * wr, 30 * wr, 'white')
    drawCircle(turtle, x - 40 * wr, y + 60 * wr, 10 * wr, 'black')
    drawCircle(turtle, x + 50 * wr, y + 60 * wr, 40 * wr, 'white')
    drawCircle(turtle, x + 50 * wr, y + 60 * wr, 10 * wr, 'black')
    drawCircle(turtle, x + 0 * wr, y + 20 * wr, 10 * wr, 'black')
    drawCircle(turtle, x + 0 * wr, y - 80 * wr, 40 * wr, 'brown')

def left():
    global global_xx

    screen.onkey(None, 'Left')  # disable handler inside handler

    global_xx -= 10
    mySmile(turtle, global_xx, 0, 0.3)

    screen.update()
    screen.onkey(left, 'Left')

def right():
    global global_xx

    screen.onkey(None, 'Right')

    global_xx += 10
    mySmile(turtle, global_xx, 0, 0.3)

    screen.update()
    screen.onkey(right, 'Right')

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

mySmile(turtle, global_xx, 0, 0.3)

screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

screen.tracer(0, 0)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is not working in trinket.io website

TypeError : TypeError: <native JS>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visible' on line 39 in main.py

Comment: cdlane, I'm sorry. I should have mentioned it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call the render function and clear the screen everytime you move left and right.

```
global_xx = 0
def left():
 global global_xx
 global_xx -= 10
 A.clear()
 turtle.backward(10)
 MySmile(A, 0, 0.3)

def right():
 global global_xx
 global_xx += 10
 A.clear()
 turtle.forward(10)
 MySmile(A, 0, 0.3)


def MySmile(A,yy,wr):
 global global_xx
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy-100*wr,150*wr,'green')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx-40*wr,yy+60*wr,30*wr,'white')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx-40*wr,yy+60*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+50*wr,yy+60*wr,40*wr,'white')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+50*wr,yy+60*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy+20*wr,10*wr,'black')
 DrawCircle(A,global_xx+0*wr,yy-80*wr,40*wr,'brown')
```